# Custom URL for Custom Post Type & Custom Taxonomy Term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

i created a custom post type called "career" and a custom taxonomy called "hubs" with 4 terms "hub1", "hub2", "hub3" and "hub4". I created both with the Toolset Plugin (https://wp-types.com/).

The standard URL structure is

```
website.com/career/post-name
```

i need the structure like this (without taxonomy, just the terms):

```
website.com/career/hub1/post-name
website.com/career/hub2/post-name
website.com/career/hub3/post-name
website.com/career/hub4/post-name
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin could help you ?

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-taxonomy-base-slug/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but its not what im searching. Last updated: 4 years ago and then i still dont know how to add the terms to my urls. A solution without a plugin would be great.

Comment: You can try create custom rewrite rules after save/update taxonomy https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule